# JSP - Usar request em um método

Tags: java, jsp

Estou tentando utilizar um request dentro de um método como segue:

```
<%!                
    public void method()
    {
        RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
        disp.forward(request, response);
    };
%>
```

Porém o mesmo está apontando erro no request..
Acredito que possa ser algo referente a falta de import para o objeto request, mas já tentei alguns importrs e não surgiu efeito..

Se eu utilizo o request fora do método o mesmo funciona, assim:

```
<%    
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Páginas JSP são traduzidas para Servlets e então compiladas.

Existe uma diferença sobre como a tradução trata [Scriptlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) (`<% %>`) e [Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html) (`<%! %>`).

*Scritplets* são traduzidos para um método de serviço que disponibiliza variáveis como `request` e `response`. Por exemplo, seu *Scriptlet* é traduzido para a construção abaixo no Tomcat 8 / Jasper:

```
public void _jspService(final HttpServletRequest request, 
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final PageContext pageContext;
    HttpSession session = null;
    final ServletContext application;
    final ServletConfig config;
    JspWriter out = null;
    final Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;

    try {
        pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
                null, true, 8192, true);
        _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
        application = pageContext.getServletContext();
        config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
        session = pageContext.getSession();
        out = pageContext.getOut();
        _jspx_out = out;

        // Aqui esta o seu codigo real
        RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
        disp.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // linhas e linhas de boilerplate    
    } finally {
        _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
    }
}
```

Veja que só é possível usar o `request` pois o mesmo foi passado para o método de serviço por parâmetro.

*Declarations* por sua vez são simplesmente copiadas para o corpo do Servlet durante a tradução, logo você não terá acesso ao `request` por padrão. Nada te impede porém de receber `request` e `response` como parâmetros:

```
<%!
  public void method(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
          throws ServletException, IOException {
      RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
      disp.forward(request, response);
  };
%>
```

Isso é equivalente a declarar um método no corpo de um `Servlet`. 
Conforme a resposta do [Max Rogério](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60732/max-rog%c3%a9rio), somente declarar o método não é suficiente. É necessário invocar o método que foi declarado. Para tanto uma opção possível é escrever um *Scriptlet* que invoque o método repassando `request` e `response`:

```
<%
  method(request, response);
%>
```

Isso faz o que você quer... Dito isso, vejo pouca razão para fazer um *foward* dessa forma já que o JSP disponibiliza a tag [`<jsp:forward>`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-forward-action-tag/) que faz a mesma coisa:

```
<jsp:forward page="t2.jsp" />
```

No geral é melhor evitar *Scriptlets* e *Declarations*, além de ser uma tecnologia legada, arquiteturalmente eles são uma abominação... Misturar código de negócio com regras de navegação e a *view* em um único lugar cria uma salada bem difícil de manter.

Answer (score 0):

Você cria métodos ou função para nao ficar reescrevendo coisas repetidas.
No seu caso você somente criou um método e nada mais.
Para ele funcionar você tem que chamar ele.

```html
// criando metodo ou funcao
public void method()
{
    //sequencia de código que será executada ao chamar metodo ou funcao
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
};

//utilizando metodo ou funcao
method();
```

No caso se estivesse em alguma classe ficaria mais ou menos assim

```html
public class Teste{
// criando metodo ou funcao
public void mudaTela()
{
    //sequencia de código que será executada ao chamar metodo ou funcao
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("t2.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
};
}

//na pagina do jsp vc faz import da class
Teste t = New Teste();
t.mudaTela();
```

Eu não testei os códigos. Mas a ideia é q quando vc cria um método, você tem q chama-lo para ele ser executado.

Comment: Oi Max, tem um problema maior aqui. `request` não estará disponível dentro do método. O único motivo pelo qual ele funciona no segundo scriptlet do OP é a maneira como arquivos JSPs são compilados para Servlets... Basicamente o corpo do scriptlet vai para um método `service` que possui parâmetros `request` e `response`... Já a declaração (`<%!`) coloca o método do OP no corpo do Servlet (que não possui acesso ao `request`). Ou seja, sua resposta infelizmente não vai funcionar.

Comment: Malz ae entao, mexi faz uns meses com JSP e dei uma parada.